# Copying from SPS2003 explorer view to local folder: "Edit Items" required?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

When i want to copy from a document library in a SPS2003-site, only
"View items" and "Browse directories" is not enough! If i try to copy
from explorer view to my local hard drive, I get "access denied"
error.
When I give myself "View items", "Browse directories" AND "Edit items"
it works!
The properties of the original document are not changed during copy
(of course not), so I have no idea why I need Edit Items-permission.
I can't find anything on Google that points to a solution to my
problem. I don't want to give anyone Edit items permission to just
copy files from the site.

When I make my test-account  "Administrator"  or "Web Designer" or
"Contributor" permission, it works fine.
Anyone in the company is "Reader" and can open the documents through
the list-view. But, we are migrating towards MOSS2007 and some people
with only "Reader"-permission on SPS2003 has to be able to copy the
documents using explorer view to their local drive.

So, "Readers" cannot copy files from SPS2003 to a local folder using
Explorer View; i have to grant them at least Contributor-rights...
That is strange, isn't it?
Executed steps:
- SPS2003 library -> Explorer view
- Select documents and copy with CTRL+C
- Open My Documents and paste with CTRL+C
- Explorer error: "Access denied, make sure the disk is not full or
write protected and that the file is not currently in use" when
"Reader". If "Contributor", no error occurs.

Can anyone help? I have really no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm Kevin and I work on SharePoint.. I asked around a bit and found out that in SPS 2003 we gated all WebDav requests with the 'edit item' permission. We relaxed this restriction in SharePoint 2007.